# Cannot remove or find an object in Java's CopyOnWriteArraySet

Tags: java, collections, set

I use CopyOnWriteArraySet to store one instance of a custom class, which looks like this:

```
public class MyClass{
 String _name;

 public MyClass(String name){
  _name = name;
 }

 @Override
 public int hashCode(){
  return _name.hashCode();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj){
  if (obj == this) return true;
  if ((obj instanceof MyClass) == false) return false;
  MyClass otherObject = (MyClass) obj;
  return _name.equals(otherObject._name);
 }

 @Override
 public String toString(){
  return _name;
 }
}
```

When I print the set, everything seems ok:

```
MyClass theObject = new MyClass("Object 1");
CopyOnWriteArraySet<MyClass> theSet = new CopyOnWriteArraySet();
theSet.add(theObject);

for (MyClass tmp : theSet){
 System.out.println(tmp.toString());
}
```

The result is:

> Object 1

So, obviously the object is in the set.

Now, I want to remove the object from the set:

```
theSet.remove(theObject);
```

Then I print the content of the set again.
The result:

> Object 1

Very weird. So, I tried this:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(theSet.contains(theObject)));
```

The result:

> false

Obviously, the set cannot find `theObject` although it's there.
So, I thought, there's something wrong with the `equals()` method.
Thus, I changed the method overrides of `equals()` and `hashCode()` by adding a console print to the first line of each function:

```
 @Override
 public int hashCode(){
  System.out.println("hashCode() called");
  return _name.hashCode();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj){
  System.out.println("equals() called");
  if (obj == this) return true;
  if ((obj instanceof MyClass) == false) return false;
  MyClass otherObject = (MyClass) obj;
  return _name.equals(otherObject.name);
 }
```

Then, I call again:

```
theSet.remove(theObject);
```

The result:

> hashCode() called

So, the `equals()` method isn't called at all?

Can someone explain what's going on there?

I already tried to compare the hashCodes of `theObject` and the instance inside the set and they're both equal.

Comment: The question title says `CopyOnWriteArraySet` but the code says `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. Which are you actually using? What value does `remove()` return - if false, the list did not contain the element.

Comment: If you want a Set in order to not allow duplicate items, use `CopyOnWriteArraySet`

Comment: @Matt Ball Sorry, my mistake. I corrected to CopyOnWriteArraySet. remove() returns false.

Comment: Then the set thinks that it does not contain the element you're trying to remove.

Comment: @Matt Ball Yes, I know because as I already posted: `setSet.contains(theObject)` returns false. The question is: Why?

Comment: Perhaps because you have not overridden `equals()` correctly.

Comment: what peter said. and learn to use debugger, just step into the code and check the intermediate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the problem.

I'm using Hibernate which creates an own instance of org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet which replaced my CopyOnWriteArraySet!

The fact that .contains() and .remove() didn't work was a bug in Hibernate: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3799

The solution in my case was **to not override** the .hashCode() method.

**Note:** This might not be the best solution for all cases. For me, it worked though.
In the link above, there are several workarounds described.

Answer (score 1):

Strange..i have tested your codes. And it works well in my environment.
And the remove operation doesn't call hashCode() but call equals() instead.
The jdk what i used is 1.6.0_23.

Answer (score 0):

HashSet's use the hashCode, however the CopyOnWriteArraySet is not a HashSet (neither is TreeSet) and neither call hashCode(). If hashCode is being called you are not using this collection.

---

It is very weird because I cannot reproduce your problem.

```
MyClass theObject = new MyClass("Object 1");
CopyOnWriteArrayList<MyClass> theSet = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();
// OR
CopyOnWriteArraySet<MyClass> theSet = new CopyOnWriteArraySet();

theSet.add(theObject);
System.out.println("After add.");
System.out.println(theSet);

theSet.remove(theObject);
System.out.println("\nAfter remove");
System.out.println(theSet);
```

prints

```
After add.
[Object 1]

After remove
[]
```

Even when I change hashCode to

```
public int hashCode() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

it gets the same result because these classes don't use hashCode() (except in the  hashCode() method)

Comment: Hm, the code that I posted was just a simplified version of my real code which I cannot post here since it's very complicated and verbose. However, since you cannot reproduce the problem, I assume that the cause must be somewhere in my "complicated" code. I just don't understand why it's not working for me and why equals() is not called. How does Set determine if an object exists inside without using equals()?

Comment: @valmar - Try to reproduce the problem yourself with a not so simplified version of the code. If the problem is still there, simplify it some more. Do this until you either figure out what the problem is, or you have a simple enough example which demonstrates the issue and you can post it here for others to try.

Comment: @valmar, HashSet's use the hashCode, however the CopyOnWriteArraySet is not a HashSet (neither is TreeSet) and neither call hashCode(). If hashCode is being called you are not using this collection.

Comment: You were right! I'm using Hibernate which creates an own instance of org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet which replaced my CopyOnWriteArraySet! Thanks so much. At least, now I know what's wrong. If you post your comment as a real answer, I'll gladly mark it as "the right answer".

Comment: I also found out why .remove() and .contains() failed. The reason was a bug in Hibernate which interfered with the .hasCode() method (see my answer to this question for more info).